# What amount of inbound traffic is considered as normal for a small blog?

Tags: web-hosting, network-traffic

I have a blog that has ~1000 page views per day. Usually the amount of incoming traffic to the web server was less than 5MB. Suddenly it popped up to 300MB for some longer period of time. This is 60 times more than usual. I asked the hosting support about that problem, and thy gave me the feedback that 300MB is not considered as a big incoming traffic. What is your expert opinion on that. The server is VPS.

[image]

where day before I had normal (low) inbound traffic.

[image]

Comment: That depends on your content. Did you suddenly have some big graphics on the homepage? Traffic depends on the kind of application and they probably saw those 300 MB in contrast to their whole user base.

Comment: Well, no, no big graphics. I actually saw the "anomaly" myself. I will upload the image to share.

Comment: as you can see from the graphics the "anomaly" was present for some 10h, and then it vanished to the normal daily values, in average below 5MB.

Comment: The question you have up is whenever or not 300 MB of traffic is much and as long as the server isn't hosted on a mobile hotspot in Germany 300 MB traffic is just nothing. Most youtube videos are probably bigger. You're right that it's a big spike in comparison to your usual traffic. In addition if you look at what actually happened someone "uploaded" data to your server. It might just be invalid posts and some kind of DDoS that was run on some other machine on that box. In addition there is the answer from mzhaase. With this little information this is about it I guess.

Comment: since the requests are small chunks of information, I would agree with you that I had some kind of DDoS, or simple DoS, although my kernel based firewall should take care of DoS. This brings the conclusion to my story, that I had relatively big spike, comparing the my usual traffic. So I will ask another questions to get the feedback what to do.

Comment: I know that almost half of the web traffic is fake, and sometimes we are unable to suppress some fake traffic, but this question was not about that. I just wanted to consider and get the expert opinion on incoming traffic quantities, and I don't see legit reasons to down vote questions like this.

Comment: I have no idea who downvoted it but your first question was certainly lacking and to be honest the question is very broad without knowing a lot of details. Hence why I assumed a big picture on your website, before realizing you were talking about posting data.

Comment: you may be right re the lacking of the details, but there are allays ways to ask for more info; in this case I may have said 300MB/**hour**. thanks man this may be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact amount of traffic is usually less important than the relative change. 300 MB is not big incoming traffic but it **is** an anomaly for your blog. Whenever an anomaly is encountered, steps should be taken to investigate if anything malicious happened. Especially incoming traffic is suspicious since it is most likely a blog where users cannot upload media. So where did those 300 MB come from? First, it should be checked whether there were simply more users in that time frame, which would explain the anomaly. It is also a possiblity, however, that someone got access to the server blog and downloaded a payload to it.